# Why isn't this string parsing as a date?

Tags: python, date

This is driving me crazy. I've looked and looked at the strptime documentation and can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working. Please help!

```
import datetime    
a = '20180615 16:00 EST'
datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z')

Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
            exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
          File "<ipython-input-30-d72261c0e1d6>", line 1, in <module>
            datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z')
          File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
            tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
          File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
            (data_string, format))
        ValueError: time data '20180615 16:00 EST' does not match format '%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z'
```

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue22377

Comment: Wow, unfixed since 2014? Even the documentation does not mention this issue. That makes me sad... Python sometimes is so unpythonic.

Comment: Works without 'EST' and `%Z` but gives error when included